# Xcode always says ‘FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit’.h file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

No matter what I do (I may be doing it wrong) When I try to build my unity IOS app for testing, Xcode always says ‘FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit’.h file not found.

I’ve added the Facebook SDK indicated in the Quick Start for iOS in the Xcode Project.
From the Facebook SDK folder, dragged the folder FBSDKCoreKit.Framework, FBSDKLoginKit.Framework, FBSDKShareKit.Framework into your Xcode Projects Framework folder. Then configured info.plist as stated and of course supplied the bundle identifier. And it gives the same problem. 
Honestly I have spent more than 6 weeks on this single issue. I’m in the verge of mental and physical collapse and close to be fired. Please give some kind of advice. I’ve tried all the other answers in this same page but non work. Please help!!

Answer (score 63):

I had this problem with XCode 10!!!
Sorted in this way:

- Select `Libraries > RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj`
- Select `Build Settings > Framework Search Paths`
- Replace the `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` to `$(HOME)/Documents/FacebookSDK` (with parentheses!)

Believe it or not, now it works!

Comment: You helped resolving a big headache, bless you

Comment: You rock. Thanks

Comment: U da real mvp! thanX!

Answer (score 18):

If you're here because you're trying to use facebook/react-native-fbsdk, then you only need to add the following line to your Podfile:

```
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

Then

`pod install`

Build and run!

Comment: Where is podfile ? Could you please explain more about this

Comment: @AkilaDevinda it's part of CocoaPods dependency manager. Initially, it doesn't exist, but if you need to add some dependencies, like Google Maps, you may use it. It exists at the root of the iOS project. Its content is usually described as part of the library's readme (i.e. the library you're trying to add to the project). For more info, see: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html
However, I would guess your issue can't be fixed with Podfile if you haven't used it in your project.

Comment: In my case this worked out. Also this is the most logically comprehensible solution

Comment: The [cocoapods fbsdk page](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FBSDKShareKit) was very helpful too

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue and solve problem.<>
My solution : 
1. follow the steps from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/getting-started-ios
2. check the xcode proj -> Library, find and open file RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj then update fb sdk path in build setting->Framework search path.

It works.
I guess that sometime the RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj in Library can not update the framework search path from main xcodeproj so we need done manually.
Hopefully my solution can help you, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to look there at all. My tunnel vision had me trying to figure out what was going on in my project itself and not RCTFBSDK

Answer (score 2):

Drekka I was finally out of the game, until I read this answer and it gave my an Idea to try something different.
This is what finally worked for me:
The Framework Search Path was set wrong I it was such I tiny detail I wuold never noticed it if I was wasn't obsessed about it:
In target - build settings - search paths - frameworks search paths change from:

$(inherited) 
$(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks\Plugins/iOS/Facebook (look at the wrong direction of the first slash)

to

$(SCROOT) 
$(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks/Plugins/iOS/Facebook

This is finally it I can go to sleep now!Thanks drekka!

Comment: What worked for me in Framework Search Path: ~/Documents/FacebookSDK ...couldn't believe it

Answer (score 2):

If you think you've done everything right but it still is not working, then make sure the FB [LoginKit, ShareKit, and CoreKit] are in your "Copy Bundle Resources".

[image]

This took me hours to figure out, hope it can help others!

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell what your problem is and I've never used those frameworks. But it sounds like you may have added them to the project in terms of linking against them during compilation, but they are not being added to the final app bundle.

This may or may not help, but based on what you have said, it's what I would look at. Check your 'Build Phases'. You should see the frameworks in the 'Link Binary With Libraries' phase. You then need to look for a phase ( or add one if it's not there) which is a 'Copy files Phase'. Add one by choosing 'New Copy Files Phase' after clicking the '+' at the top of the list.

In the 'Copy Files Phase', set the 'Destination' to 'Frameworks' and then add the Facebook frameworks to the list of file to copy.

Another option which may also work if the above doesn't is to check the 'Runpath Search Paths' in your build settings. If it's not set, try setting it to '@executable_path/Frameworks @loader_path/Frameworks'.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS, in my case, I followed all the instructions but I still got the error. I check again, the files were "there":
[image]

But actually they're on my iCloud account instead (notice the ones with a little cloud icon). So I downloaded those files to my disk and the app successfully  compiled !

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't installed cocoapods first:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

then go to your Xcode project directory and do

```
pod install
```

it should create a .xcworkspace open it and build your project. You will have no problem.

The .xcworkspace must be created by cocoa pods not Unity. Sometimes unity creates it so it's missing Pods that's why Xcode can't find some libraries.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers ended up not working for me. What did work in the end was changing the Facebook SDK folder name to FacebookSDK and moving it to Documents on my Macbook. Remember to also change the Frameworks search path under build settings accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while building game for iOS via Unity3D.

Basically newer versions of facebook sdk do not include frameworks, it is expected of you to download them using cocoapods.

So, after compiling via unity while on windows, I copied my resulting folder and pasted it into my macbook.

You then need to call the `pod install` command from that folder (by opening Terminal and navigating to the folder where your xcode is, then executing `pod install`). Cocoapods will download what you need, and then you can compile.

It might take 20 minutes until `pod install` actually completes. To me it seamed frozen, but you can open Resource Monitor and see under the Network tab that Cocoapods indeed is downloading stuff from internet. So just give it some time.

Then, look in the terminal for the further instructions (basically it will generate a new file, through which you must open your project from now on).

Answer (score 0):

FB Sdk above Version 7.16.1 have this issue. Actually it have no files in framework folder.

This error remove when you build it using FBSDK v7.16.1, but Appstore got rejected the app, because of depreciated api usage(UIWebView).

I resolve it by using FBSDK v7.19.2.

1) When you build the project for xcode it shows the mention error, shareKit not found. I resolve it by copy the facebookSDK folder from the framework folder of my previous build(with fbsdk v7.16.1), into the same location of the current xcode folder(frameworks/FacebookSDK....)

2) Then, open your xcode project, add files from location: Frameworks/FacebookSDK/Plugins/IOS/ (sharekit, corekit, loginkit) into Frameworks in Xcode.

3) Add "$(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks/FacebookSDK/Plugins/iOS" into Framework Search Paths into build settings at Xcode.

4) Open Project into Terminal: type "grep -r "UIWebView" ." , if this shows any match with UIWebView remove it by opening the file.

5) If it shows match in a binary file of FBSDKCoreKit. Open the file in TextEdit at MAC and Find and Replace all "UIWebView" to "WKWebView"

6) Save it and again add it into Frameworks at Xcode. Build and push to appstore.